# The styling of my sidebar widget is wrong

Tags: css, html-lists

I have created a custom HTML widget and added it to my sidebar. Here is the link:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/

This is what it looks like when I inspect the element:

[image: Downloads]

When I compare it with the Recent Posts section it looks like this:

[image: Recent Posts]

From what I can tell the stylings are the same but clearly they are not. I have missed something, most likely staring me in the face. I want the Downloads `<ul>` to look like the Recent Posts `<ul>`.

## Update

As mentioned in the comments, I noticed that there is an additional `<div>` wrapped around the `<ul>`:

```
<section id="custom_html-2" class="widget_text widget animation-video-sidebar widget_custom_html">
    <h2 class="widget-title">Downloads</h2>
    <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/available-downloads/">
            View Available Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

The introduction of `<div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">` was done by Wordpress I assume because my custom HTML content for the widget is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/available-downloads/">View Available Downloads</a></li>
</ul>
```

I added this to the **Additional CSS** area:

```
/* AJT 28-05-2018 Downloads Sidebar Item */
.custom-html-widget 
{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

It now renders correctly:

[image: Results]

Is there a better way to fix this with styling?

Comment: The `ul` in the Downloads section is wrapped in an additional `<div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">...</div>`, whereas the one in Recent Posts is not; and the `textwidget` class adds 10px padding …

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I noticed this once I viewed the source and copied it into Expression Web. It wasn't standing out at me at the time. I did some tweaks to my question. I would have preferred that my styling was just applied to that specific item as opposed to a class that might end up being used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I was able to come up with the correct CSS styling:

```
#custom_html-2 .textwidget
{
  padding: 0px;
}
```